# How to access the view from within dataview's tpl in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to test against a combobox value from inside dataview's tpl:

```
Ext.define('MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'my_combo',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<tpl if="this.test()">pass</tpl>',
                '</tpl>'
            , 
            {
                test: function(){
                    //doesn't work
                    return this.getView().down('[name=my_combo]').getValue() == 'ok';
                }
            }),
        }
    ]
});
```

This doesn't work because `this` is referencing to the template itself and I can't figure out how to access the view from the inside.

Comment: You cannot reference a view in XTemplate function. Probably its better to use ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to access a view in XTemplate. To achieve this you can use ViewModel, here is the code for it.

And working sencha fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/175s

**Update:** I updated the code to use the DataView, DataView is little tricky, i overwritten the prepareData method to pass in extra information to the template and also updating the DataView whenever the combo value is changed. Here is the fiddle with updated changes https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/175s

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'myForm',
    defaults: {
        padding: 10
    },

    viewModel: {  
        stores: {
            employeeStore: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'John'
                }, {
                    name: 'Tempel'
                }, {
                    name: 'George'
                }, {
                    name: 'Milinda'
                }]
            },
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'nameField',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            reference: 'emp',
            bind: {
                store: '{employeeStore}',
                value: '{name}'
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            itemId: 'empList',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div class="dataview-multisort-item">',
                        '<h3>{name}</h3>',
                         '<tpl if="passed">Selected</tpl>',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
            ),
            itemSelector: 'div.dataview-multisort-item',

            bind: {
                store: '{employeeStore}'
            },

            prepareData: function(data, index, record) {
                 var name = this.up().getViewModel().get('name');
                 var passed = record.get('name') == name;
                 return Ext.apply({passed: passed}, data);
            }
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var me = this;

        // refresh the dataview when name is changed.
        this.getViewModel().bind('{name}', function() {
            var dataview = me.down('#empList');
            dataview.refresh();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I access values from ViewModel inside a dataview template, by using `bind`?

Comment: DataView works with Store, But we are dealing with a single value. So may i know why you want to use DataView for a single value ?

Comment: I'm not dealing with a single value, I have a dataview like this: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#dataview-multisort , and I need to check for some condition inside that dataview template which is calculated based on another combobox value.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to avoid, to inject data into the store. Oh well, if there is no better way. Thanks.

Comment: return Ext.apply({passed: passed}, data);  Just in case if we don't want underlying model to be modified.